# $http.get requests with localhost address when deploying on cloud server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I have an AngularJS factory function like:

```js
service.getUserRates = function() {
  return $http.get('https://localhost:8443/portfolio/get-user-rates');
}
```

This works fine on localhost, but before deploying on digital ocean servers I have to update the URL to include the IP address of the server -  `$http.get('http://67.205.xx.xxx:8443`, instead of `localhost` or I get an `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error.

This is hard to manage since I am developing on local machine and pulling changes into cloud server, I have to keep changing the URL every time I do a new git push / pull.

What is the easiest / best way to manage this so I don't have to manually change the URLs repeatedly?

Comment: what is your server side application ? do you listen on all interfaces of you machine using 0.0.0.0 ?

Comment: Can't you use a tool like gulpjs or gruntjs to swap those URLs for you in a build chain in your development workflow?

Comment: server is express. listen on port 8443.

Comment: are you using any build tool like webpack?

Comment: No not using any build tool. Will look into that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use root relative URLs:

```
 app.service("dataService", function() {
     this.getUserRates = function() {
         return $http.get('/portfolio/get-user-rates');
     }         
 });
```

> In general, it is considered best-practice to use relative URLs, so that your website will not be bound to the base URL of where it is currently deployed. For example, it will be able to work on localhost, as well as on your public domain, without modifications.
>
> [— StackOverFlow: Absolute vs relative URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2005097/5535245)

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution that I've seen before is to replace all occurrences of

`https://localhost:8443`

with

`$window.location.protocol + '//' + $window.location.host`

You can always use an `angular.module('yourAppName').constant` to share the hostname around the entire application.

This has the added benefit of supporting subdomains out of the box. You don't have to change anything to deploy code to `test.yourdomain.com` or `stage.yourdomain.com`.